# How to reinitialize a notebook from the shell?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, ijulia-notebook

Following [previous discussions](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/julia-on-google-colab-free-gpu-accelerated-shareable-notebooks/15319) from 2018, I managed to run the latest version of Julia inside Google Colab (see [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RmYwV4jrlcR0rtWaYCyckTyfWoNthMTr?usp=sharing)). However, there is a small quirk in the setup: after installing Julia, a new notebook has to be initialized before Colab will recognize Julia code. I've been doing this by refreshing the web browser, which seems like it doesn't kill the runtime environment while reinitializing the notebook.

I would like to remove this quirky step, and have it so that the notebook is reinitialized directly after Julia is installed, without the need to refresh the browser. Is there a simple shell command that will do this? Any ideas are appreciated.

(The Colab notebook I provided in the link above has step-by-step instructions for installing and running Julia, including instructions on when to refresh the browser. It's short.)